# How to give a roll only access to add a certain content type?

Tags: 8, users

In D8:
I have a content type call fooCT.
I have a role called:  "fooRole"

I give fooRole the following permissions:

- fooCT: create fooCT
- use simple editor

So the checkbox: View published content is not checked

A person with this role cannot do anything in the system anymore.

How to give this person only access to add a a fooCT?

I tried several options but do not get the desired result.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Permission `View published content` is very important, without the users of that role won't be able to see Published content. What do you mean by "cannot do anything in the system anymore"?

Do you want that Role to be able to create new nodes of that type, but not to be able to View those nodes once they're created?

You should look into the `Editorial` Workflow, and [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module.

Comment: Yes i would like that users can only create new nodes but not able to view it.

Comment: The two things I mentioned are then the way to go. Unless it's more of a case for Webform. Usually if you just want to gather data but not allow View access it's a survey type of data, not a common node.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why can they NOT access published content. All users need that to view the node. It maybe interesting to start enabling access to this user to get a better understanding of each permission.

Comment: the user is only allowed the entry a new fooCT. That's just the business case. After that the process continue.